# How do you query entries by field values?

Tags: craft3

I need to arbitrarily query entries based on the values of various fields.

For example, if I have an entry type called "Widgets" I can grab them like this:

```
$widgets = Entry::find()->section('widget')->all();
```

Now what if widgets have a field called "widgetColor" and I want to select all with a value of "blue" in that field?

1. How can I query for those entries?
2. Also, how can I query for any entry with no value in that field?

I've tried my best to figure it out using the documentation and it seems like method such as `where` only apply to certain data, such as the title and slug, which are not custom fields on the entry type.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can do the same like with the section, if the query param exists in the field layout

```
$widgets = Entry::find()->widgetColor('blue')->text(':notempty:')->anotherField(':empty:')->section('widget')->all();
```

Will search for entries where `widgetColor` is blue, `text` is not empty/null and `anotherField` is empty/null

**Edit: just for people who like to understand the behavior**

Just to explain you the `where` parameter in the `ElementQuery`. The `where` function uses the Yii2 Query function directly and works directly at the database layer. When you take a look at your `content` table you'll see all custom fields have a certain prefix (if you didn't change it) so your `widgetColor` column will look like `field_widgetColor` when you do

```
where->(['widgetColor' => 'blue');
```

it will query

```
where `content`.`widgetColor` = `blue`
```

which will throw an error since the column name is `field_widgetColor`. The `__set` function in the `Yii/component`/ `QueryBuilder` class will set magic property that exists because of the field handle in your field layout... Or to keep it simple: you can access any "magic" property with the same name like an existing field handle.

Doing

```
->widgetColor($property)
```

will call the `__set` function that calls a wrapper that will wrap/attach the field content prefix (`field_`) to the `where` function. Thus you can use

```
where->(['field_widgetColor' => 'blue');
```

or

```
where->([Craft::$app->getFields()->oldFieldColumnPrefix . 'widgetColor' => 'blue');
```